# sendPronto data type?

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno, arduino-ide

I can't seem to figure out what the data type for sendPronto is. It's a function in the IRremote library and I basically have hundreds of Pronto Hex values that I want to shuv into a array called Dataset. If you don't do a integer it would look like the following:

irsend.sendPronto("PRONTO=HERE");

But when I do an array that uses the int counter to go up 1 by one.

irsend.sendPronto(Dataset[Counter]);

it outputs: no matching function for call to 'IRsend::sendPronto(String&)'

I have tried all the datatypes I know of and can't find any material helping the situation. Please help and thank you <3

Comment: My first guess would be that it is a char array.  Strings are pretty wasteful and aren't very well suited for limited environments like Arduino.  Most good coders will use char arrays instead.

Comment: A quick look at the source code for the library confirms this.

Comment: In case you didn't know, there is a Stack specifically for the Arduino,  https://arduino.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick look at the source code for the library on Github shows that function as taking a char* (ie a char array) as the data type.